# How to handle KeyStoreException caused by creation of EncryptedSharedPreferences?

Tags: androidx, androidx-security

For the most part, the application works fine. At times I get the following exception:

> android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid operation handle

Here is the stack trace:

```
android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException KeyStore.java:1550
android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:531
javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal Cipher.java:2267
com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encrypt AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:71
androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:153
androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:119
```

**Code:**

```kotlin
fun getEncryptedSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences {
    val context = appContext
    val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
        .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
        .build()
    return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        context,
        SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,
        masterKey,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
}
```

I have no idea what to make of this. How do I handle this?